# Having trouble with java.util.localdate

Tags: java

Good morning! I am having some trouble with figuring out potential problems I could be having with this code I am trying to write in order to be able to pass my own date to it and retrieve some information as what you can see right there below. The main issue according to my editor seems to be that of a colliding `LocalDate` variable with a `String` one and I've already tried to convert it to a `String` with no success. Whatever `parse()` or `toString()` methods I would use would always harm the code even more (I particularly tried the latter in the constructor `DateAnalyzer()` a lot and the former in my `getDate()` function). The idea is that I have to work within the `java.util.LocalDate` so I would greatly appreciate any help coming my way concerning this library. Thank you in advance!

```
package fact.it.exercisedateanalyzer.model;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

public class DateAnalyzer {
    private LocalDate date;

    public DateAnalyzer(String date) {
    }

    public int getNumberedDayOfTheYear() {
        return LocalDate.now().getDayOfYear();
    }

    public int getNumberedDayOfTheMonth() {
        return LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth();
    }

    public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
        return LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();
    }

    public Month getMonth() {
        return LocalDate.now().getMonth();
    }

    public String get100DaysOld() {
        return LocalDate.now().plusDays(100).toString();
    }

    public String get10MonthsOld() {
        return LocalDate.now().plusMonths(10).toString();
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return LocalDate.parse(date.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method `getDate()` you use `LocalDate.parse`. This method is used to convert String to LocalDate and not the other way. (The return type of LocalDate.parse is LocalDate).

If you want to convert your LocalDate-variable to a String, you can do the following:

```
return date.toString(); //returns in format uuuu-MM-dd
```

I prefer to use a DateTimeFormatter where you can get the format of your choice. Example:

```
return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd").format(date)
```

For more patterns have a look at the Documentation of DateTimeFormatter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns

Edit:

You also need to adapt your constructor to initialize the date variable in your DateAnalyzer like that (with DateTimeFormatter to pass a pattern of your choice):

```
public DateAnalyzer(String date) {
    this.date = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd"));
}
```

other way:

```
public DateAnalyzer(String date) {
    this.date = LocalDate.parse(date); //parses Strings in format uuuu-MM-dd
}
```

Edit 2:

In your other methods you use `LocalDate.now()` which delivers a LocalDate-variable. If you want to analyze the date you pass in the constructor,replace this occurences with the name of your variable.

Example for your `getDayOfWeek()`-method:

```
public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
    return date.getDayOfWeek();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, it definitely helped, now all that remains is that when I try calling out a print with the .getDate() method it gives me an error in the console upon running it. 2 other solid warnings remain in IntelliJ IDEA (my editor) regarding that the 'date' parameter is never used and that it's never assigned despite the fact that in the main application I created a new DateAnalyzer("2001-06-18").

Comment: See my edit. You need to initialize your date variable in your DateAnalyzer.

Comment: In your other methods you use `LocalDate.now()` which delivers a LocalDate-variable. If you want to analyze the LocalDate you pass in the constructor replace this occurences with the name of your variable.

Comment: I changed all the LocalDate.now() instances to date.getDayOfWeek() for example and I initialized the variable in my constructor but unfortunately now there's an error regarding that "I am trying to set incompatible types of variables equal to each other" and that the "Field 'date' may be final".

Comment: Oh, i missed that your constructor-parameter is a String. There you need to use `LocalDate.parse(...)` to parse the String to LocalDate.
I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: @bogdanlazar Please understand that this place isnt programming school were tutors sit down with you and work with you through all parts of your program from start to finish. You learn programming mainly by doing it yourself. When something doesnt work: you try to research it yourself. Sure, it is very convenient to just come back with more question and have somebody else just give you the solution. But please understand that *asking others* should be your LAST choice, not your first. So please avoid this "now I have a different problem" ping pong via comments.

Comment: Thanks mate! Wanna note that it was the first way that I could actually make it work with the European date format which was the one in which I passed a date to the constructor in the Application. Cheers!

Comment: Your question was answered, so maybe accept the answer and move on. When you run into a new problem: research it thoroughly first (rest assured: all basic problems you can run into ... somebody asked about that here or elsewhere before), and only then ... write up a new question here.